# Cannot get last n elements from GraphQL with graphene_django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, graphql, graphene-python

I was trying to implement GraphQL in existing Django REST Framework. I used **graphene-django==2.2.0**

It was successfully implemented. But cannot use 'last' keyword in the request query. I am adding the schema code.

```
import graphene
from graphene_django.types import DjangoObjectType
from flowers.models import Flower


class FlowerType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Flower


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    flowers = graphene.List(FlowerType)

    def resolve_flowers(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Flower.objects.all()
```

Query

```
{
    flowers (last: 2){
        id
    }
}
```

Result

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "locations": [
        {
          "column": 12,
          "line": 2
        }
      ],
      "message": "Unknown argument \"last\" on field \"flowers\" of type \"Query\"."
    }
  ]
}
```

Do I have to modify the code in Django project? How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

In your GraphQL schema. You need to be specific about query which accept last argument and return query. Please specify return type of flower(In your case)

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
  flowers = graphene.List(FlowerType, last=graphene.Int())

  def resolve_flowers(self, args, context, info):
    query = FlowerType.get_query(context)
    return query.get(args.get('last'))

Or

query($last: Int!): ReturnType
```

And you can change your query to that

```
query($flowerId: 2) {
    flowers (last: $flowerId){
        id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply use Relay, it already provides this filter, among others.

```
class FlowerType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Flower
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)

class FlowerConnection(graphene.relay.Connection):
    class Meta:
        node = FlowerType

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    flowers = graphene.relay.ConnectionField(FlowerConnection)

    def resolve_flowers(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Flower.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

## GET LAST N POSTS

```
lastNPosts = graphene.List(PostType, N=graphene.Int())

def resolve_lastNPosts(self, info, N):
    try:
        return Post.objects.order_by('-id')[:N]
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```